# Notify parent thread when child has performed a certain action [C#]

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a parent thread (non-UI) which creates some child threads to do some jobs - at some point the parent must wait for certain tasks to be completed by the child thread - this does not mean the child is finished but only that it has reached a certain point and the parent can now continue processing ...

To illustrate please refer to the code below, obviously this isn't what my children do but it shows what I am trying to accomplish. Recall that none of these are UI threads...

```
// Parent Thread
Thread childThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Manage));
childThread.IsBackground = true;
childThread.Name = "NamedPipe Manager";
childThread.Start();

while (true)
{
... do some work ...

// wait for signal from MainThread to proceed //

... do more work
}


// Child Thread
private void Manage()
{
... do some work ...
... call some functions ...

// SIGNAL TO PARENT THAT IT CAN CONTINUE //

... do more work ...
... call more functions ...
}
```

Any one have any suggestions on how I can accomplish this task in a thread-safe manner?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a single child thread you can use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx):

```
var signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);

// child thread: signal to parent that it can continue
signal.Set();

// parent thread: wait for signal from child thread to proceed
signal.WaitOne();
```

If there's more than one child thread you can use a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.semaphore.aspx):

```
var semaphore = new Semaphore(0, numberOfChildThreads);

// child thread: signal to parent that it can continue
semaphore.Release();

// parent thread: wait for signal from each child thread to proceed
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildThreads; i++)
{
    semaphore.WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: What happens if they are in another class? For example Pareant creates A = new A(); and inside A we launch a thread that needs to .Set() the ManualResetEvent() in the parent?

Comment: Pass the signal reference along as a parameter to the A constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a [WaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy257t0.aspx) (I would add the usual code sample, but the example given in MSDN is almost exactly what you want)

Comment: Seriously? you can just make the autoevent static? I thought I would need to create the AutoEvent and somehow pass it to the children thread ... but this is a lot easier then I thought ...

And it is thread safe? Even if I have multiple children? (only need a single signal)

Comment: Yes seriously, yes it can be static, yes it is thread safe and yes the parent thread will move past the WaitOne() call until *any* other thread sets the WaitHandle. You can use multiple WaitHandles and the WaitAll call to wait for *all* the child threads to call Set()

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using explicit threads instead of BackgroundWorker? BackgroundWorker has built-in facilities for communicating progress back to the UI thread.

Comment: There is no UI thread ... this is actually a Service.
Do you still recommend using BackgroundWorkers?

Comment: Hmm. No idea; I've never tried it, and I don't know much about its implementation, so I couldn't say. So one of the other answers may be a better bet.